Extracting and assigning images from PDFs in generated markdown
So I successfully create nicely structured Markdowns using GPT4o based on PDFs. In the markdown itself I already get (fake) references to the images that appear in the PDF. Using PyMuPDF I can also extract the images that appear in the PDF. I can also bring GPT4 to describe the referenced images in the Markdown.
My question: Is there a known approach on how to assign the correct images to their reference in their markdown? Is that possible using only GPT4? Or are Layout models like LayoutLM or Document AI or similar more suitable for this tasks?
One approach I already tried is adding the base64 encoded images along with their filenames but this results in gibberish output.
